# lightning-input-field displays differently in production and sandbox

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I have the exact same code in production and sandbox.  Things look as expected in sandbox, but in production I can see different css being applied.  In Production the lightning input field is being rendered with a class of slds-form-element_horizontal.  That class isn't applied in Sanboxes though.

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={contactId} object-api-name="Contact">

        <div class="slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12"></div>

            <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12">
                <lightning-input-field disabled field-name="FirstName">
                </lightning-input-field>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12">
                <lightning-input-field disabled field-name="LastName">
                </lightning-input-field>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-12">
            </div>
        </div>


    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

Comment: is your sandbox on the same version as your production? Are your APEX Classes set up to use the most recent API version?

Comment: where is yout lightning web component being used?

Comment: is this communities?

Comment: API version 47.0 on production and sandboxes.  No Apex involved.  I made a simple test with this as a record detail.

Comment: @gneek where is this being used?Are you adding this component in another parent lightning component?

Comment: @devforce no, I made this as a simplified test. I added it right into the Lightning App Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out! I had to adjust my Display Density setting to Comfy. 
And now I see I can override that in code.
density=comfy on lightning-record-edit-form.

```
<lightning-record-edit-form density="comfy" record-id={contactId} object-api-name="Contact">
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_display_density